# How to fix "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, typeerror

I am unsure why I am getting this error

```
count=int(input ("How many donuts do you have?"))
if count <= 10:
    print ("number of donuts: " ) +str(count)
else:
    print ("Number of donuts: many")
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In python3, `print` is a *function* that returns `None`.  So, the line:

```
print ("number of donuts: " ) +str(count)
```

you have `None + str(count)`.

What you probably want is to use string formatting:

```
print ("Number of donuts: {}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 9):

Your parenthesis is in the wrong spot:

```
print ("number of donuts: " ) +str(count)
                            ^
```

Move it here:

```
print ("number of donuts: " + str(count))
                                        ^
```

Or just use a comma:

```
print("number of donuts:", count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, with python3, you can go with `f-Strings` like:

```py
print(f"number of donuts: {count}")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 *print* is no longer a statement. You want to do,

```
print( "number of donuts: " + str(count) )
```

instead of adding to print() return value (which is None)