# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'? What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, list, typeerror, displaylist

I am trying to create a Python definition to display a list and trying to add a feature where if the list is more than 10 it will display it horizontally.

Here's my code:

```
def print_vert_list(list):
index = 0
for i in list:
    if len(list) > 10:
        print (" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index])) + " ".join(list[21:21+index])
    else:
        print (" ".join(list[index]))
        index += 1
```

And here's the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "**********", line 30, in <module>
print_vert_list(file_var_list)
File "**********", line 22, in print_vert_list
print (" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index])) + " ".join(list[21:21+index])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: What does `print(list)` gives you? Are all elements in `list` strings that you can join?

Comment: Will periods interfere with it?

Answer (score 0):

You must have an element contained in the list where it is not a string. The error message is telling you that the program is breaking because you are trying to concatenate a None type with a string type. For example:

`a = "string1" + "string2"
print(a) # will give you string1string2`

But if you try
`a = None + "string1" # You will get the same error message`

Using this logic, you can add a conditional check to make sure that the element of the list is not of None type, then you could successfully concatenate it

Answer (score 0):

`print()` returns `None`. You cannot add a string to the result of a call to print as you cannot add `None` and a string

```
print(" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index])) + " ".join(list[21:21+index])
                                   end of the print call ^ ^ You cannot add a string here
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is only defined for strings (...and numbers however in another context...)

In line `print (" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index])--->>>)<<<--- + " ".join(list[21:21+index])` is a wrong parenthesis. Print function returns `NoneType` and because of this additonal parenthesis the intepreter thinks that the print statement ends here. So this additional parenthesis causes the same behavior like described in [Python 3.3 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036594/python-3-3-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-str) and so throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question then this is a solution:

```
def print_vert_list(list_items):
    if len(list_items) > 10:
        for i in list_items:
            print(i, end=' ')
    else:
        for i in list_items:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are wrong in that line. You would want:

```
print (" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index]) + " ".join(list[21:21+index]))
```

instead of:

```
print (" ".join(list[index]) + " ".join(list[11:11+index])) + " ".join(list[21:21+index])
```

which gives you an error because you try to add a string to the return value of `print`.