# Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' exit status 1

Tags: python

I keep editing my text but I keep on getting the same error!

My code:

```
import random

Female_Characters = ["Emily", "Ariel", "Jade", "Summer"]
Male_Characters = ["Blake", "Max", "Jack", "Cole", "Daniel"]
PlacesToMeet = ["Beach", "Park", "Train Station", "Cave"]
SheSaid = ["Lets go explore!", "I'm tired", "I saw a purple frog", "My tounge hurts"]
HeSaid = ["I didnt get much sleep", "I wanna go inside that cave!", "Oh, ok"]
Outcomes = ["They never got to", "They were never found again.", "They enjoyed their day and went to 
get Ice Cream!"]

ChosenFemale = random.choice(Female_Characters)
ChosenMale = random.choice(Male_Characters)
ChosenMeet = random.choice(PlacesToMeet)
ChosenShesaid = random.choice(SheSaid)
ChosenHeSaid = random.choice(HeSaid)

print ("There were two friends, their names are ") + (ChosenMale) + (", and ") + (ChosenFemale) + (".") + ("One day when they were at the") + (ChosenMeet) + (", ") + (ChosenFemale) + (" Said, ") + (ChosenShesaid) + (". Then") + (ChosenMale) + (" Said ") + (ChosenHeSaid) + (". After that, ") + random.choice(Outcomes)
```

Still new to python

Comment: You don't need to put all the strings and variables inside parentheses in the `print()` call.

Comment: Revisit your educational materials on how to write a `print` command.  You're trying to concatenate a `print` call with a string, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Prune I suspect they're using Python 2 material.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036594/how-to-fix-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-str)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect parentheses on the `print` line.

```
print("There were two friends, their names are " + ChosenMale + ", and " + ChosenFemale + "." + "One day when they were at the" + ChosenMeet + ", " + ChosenFemale + " Said, " + ChosenShesaid + ". Then" + ChosenMale + " Said " + ChosenHeSaid + ". After that, " + random.choiceOutcomes)
```

Your code was calling

```
print("There were two friends, their names are ")
```

which returns `None`, and then trying to concatenate that with all the other strings.

Maybe you were following Python 2.x instructions. In Python 2, `print` is a statement so it didn't take an argument in parentheses, but in Python 3 it's an ordinary function.

Answer (score 0):

remove the parenthesis at the end of this string

```
print("There were two friends, their names are "
```

and add it at the end of

```
random.choice(Outcomes)
```

so it should be:

```
print ("There were two friends, their names are " + (ChosenMale) + (", and ") + (ChosenFemale) + (".") + ("One day when they were at the") + (ChosenMeet) + (", ") + (ChosenFemale) + (" Said, ") + (ChosenShesaid) + (". Then") + (ChosenMale) + (" Said ") + (ChosenHeSaid) + (". After that, ") + random.choice(Outcomes))
```